# Wearing a Ring for man on right hand middle finger

Tags: sharia, men

As-Salamu-Alaikum,

Few days ago a man told me to wear a ring on my right hand at middle finger. He told me that if I use that ring I can control my angers and it will be very helpful for my career.

Now my question: Is it prohibited? and the man told me that ring was created with various type of metal.
please answer me as early as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Islam, as far as i know, there is NO such thing as the Stones have some power. or even if they do have, we are not supposed to use them for any of such benefit. As the ultimate helper is only Allah, nothing like a ring or stone in it. So i would suggest that it is better to avoid such scams, and for controlling anger follow the Sunnah which is

- Drink water
- if you are standing then sit, if sitting then lie down
- Ask for refuge of shaitan

And Allah knows the best

Comment: + attend some anger management sessions